# Use of unresolved identifier 'jpegData'

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I've wrote this piece of code:

```
guard let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9) else ...
```

I got a compiler error in Xcode stating that this method was replaced by jpegData

so I replaced the code with this:

```
guard let data = jpegData(image, 0.9) else ...
```

but now I am getting the unresolved identifier error although I am importing the UIImage framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jpegData` is an instance method of `UIImage`, so you need to call it on your `UIImage` instance, `image`.

```
guard let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9) else {...
```

When in doubt about a method name, you should always use the documentation (which is available built into Xcode as well, you can access it using `cmd+shift+0`).

Answer (score 3):

`UIImageJPEGRepresentation` function has been replaced with the new `jpegData` method on `UIImage`.

Change:

```
guard let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9) else ...
```

to:

```
guard let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9) else ...
```

Also, `UIImagePNGRepresentation` has been replaced with `pngData()`.

A complete list you can find [here](https://github.com/alexliubj/Swift-Migration-4.2)

Answer (score 2):

In new version of Swift was method `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` replaced by `jpegData`. Also you have to call this method **on** image

```
guard let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9) else { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

`guard let data = YOUR_IMAGE.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9)`